# Concatenate two record values for the displayed option in a SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, controller

I want to be able to edit the displayed text for my select menu items. I still want the select menu to take in the Id from Traveler as the value and Name as the display value. However I want to concatenate that display value with a different column in my Traveler model called destination

```
  SelectList TravelersList = new SelectList(db.Travelers.Where(c => c.TravelerId == ThisId), "Id", "Name");

  foreach(var item as TravelersList)
  {
      //Concatenate the Traveler Name with the Destination
  }

  ViewBag.Travelers = TravelersList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the `SelectList` using `.Select()` and projecting the values into `SelectListItem`

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TravelersList = db.Travelers
    .Where(c => c.TravelerId == ThisId).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Name, x.Destination)
});
ViewBag.Travelers = TravelersList;
```

In the view, it will then be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.someProperty, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Travelers, ...)
```

although I recommend you use a view model with a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Travelers`so that the view is `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.someProperty, Model.Travellers, ...)`

Comment: After adding .AsEnumerable() before .Select() this answered my question. Thanks!